# Scala reflection to get List field value by universe apply

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I defined an annotation class with a `List` field in Scala:

```
class TestAnnotation(a: String, b: List[String]) extends StaticAnnotation
```

And some classes using the annotation, e.g.:

```
@TestAnnotation("test", List("b1", "b2"))
class TestA
```

Now I want to get the class annotation values, `a` and `b`,  by reflection

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe

universe
  .typeOf[TestA]
  .typeSymbol
  .annotations
  .find(_.tree.tpe =:= universe.typeOf[TestAnnotation])
  .map(_.tree).foreach(t => {
    // Match Exceptions happen there! How to match the List fields?
    val universe.Apply(_, universe.Literal(universe.Constant(a: String)) :: universe.Literal(universe.Constant(b: List[String])) :: Nil) = t 
    println(a)
    println(b)
  })
```

How to get the `List` value from deconstructing `t` by matching it against `universe.Apply`?

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to take one step at a time - match one more layer, print, check what we get there, understand what happened, repeat.

```
universe
  .typeOf[TestA]
  .typeSymbol
  .annotations
  .find(_.tree.tpe =:= universe.typeOf[TestAnnotation])
  .map(_.tree).map(t => {
    val universe.Apply(annotation, annotationArgs) = t
    println(annotation)
    println(annotationArgs)
    println(annotationArgs.getClass.getName)
    
    val List(aTree, bTree) = annotationArgs
    println(aTree)
    println(aTree.getClass.getName)
    println(bTree)
    println(bTree.getClass.getName)
    
    val universe.Literal(universe.Constant(a: String)) = aTree
    val universe.Apply(_, bArgsTree) = bTree
    println(a)
    println(a.getClass.getName) // we found A
    println(bArgsTree)
    println(bArgsTree.getClass.getName)
    
    bArgsTree.foreach { elem =>
      println(elem)
      println(elem.getClass.getName)
    }
    val bs = bArgsTree.map { bTree =>
      val universe.Literal(universe.Constant(b: String)) = bTree
      println(b)
      println(b.getClass.getName) // we found B
      b
    }
    
    (a, bs)
  })
```

```
new ammonite.$sess.cmd0.TestAnnotation
List("test", scala.collection.immutable.List.apply[String]("b1", "b2"))
scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
"test"
scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Literal
scala.collection.immutable.List.apply[String]("b1", "b2")
scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Apply
test
java.lang.String
List("b1", "b2")
scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
"b1"
scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Literal
"b2"
scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Literal
b1
java.lang.String
b2
java.lang.String
res10: Option[(String, List[String])] = Some(("test", List("b1", "b2")))
```

Once we figoured out how it works we can refactor if into shorter form:

```
universe
  .typeOf[TestA]
  .typeSymbol
  .annotations
  .find(_.tree.tpe =:= universe.typeOf[TestAnnotation])
  .map(_.tree).map { case universe.Apply(_, List(universe.Literal(universe.Constant(a: String)), universe.Apply(_, bArgsTree))) =>  
    (a, bArgsTree.map { case universe.Literal(universe.Constant(b: String)) => b })
  }
```

```
res21: Option[(String, List[String])] = Some(("test", List("b1", "b2")))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use quasiquote

```
universe
  .typeOf[TestA]
  .typeSymbol
  .annotations
  .find(_.tree.tpe =:= universe.typeOf[TestAnnotation])
  .map(_.tree).map {
    case q"new $_($a, $_($b1, $b2))" => println(s"a=$a, b1=$b1, b2=$b2")
  }
//a="test", b1="b1", b2="b2"
```